# Good third party comment system for a custom CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, rubygems, comments, social-networking

I built a small cms for personal websites using Rails. Each site has a simple blog.

I've been looking for a good third party comment system to add to the cms.

Have you used (or know of) any "comment service" that I can seamlessly integrate via their API, and if they have a ruby gem even better.

Thanks in advance

Deb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the two above, I've found this service (formerly called jskit) interesting, and it seems to have some great Twitter-integration features: http://aboutecho.com/

Answer (score 2):

I use [disqus](http://disqus.com) - there's a [gem](http://github.com/norman/disqus) which works well with rails2 and rails3rc1 (not tried with rc2 yet, but I presume it works fine with it)

Comment: there's a nice jquery disqus plugin [here:](http://viatropos.com/blog/jquery-disqus-plugin/) - looks better than the gem to be honest as it's more upto date wrt the latest disqus features

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Intensedebate](http://intensedebate.com/) and [disqus](http://disqus.com/)

I feel Intensedebate is better.